# In lambda - how to update map dynamically from outside? [instant update is not a requirement]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, scheduler

Looking for guidance:

I have a lambda l1 with function f1 which is triggered on events from apigw, and it has a hashmap which is there to get value corresponding to the key (here key is part of the event received by lambda l1 from apigw).
And based on the value for the key, I decide to choose which DynamoDB table to be used to persist the request/event from apigw (through lambda l1)

> I want to make this map to be updated dynamically, in a way that I can
> inject updated map from outside without touching lambda l1 every time properties/map has to be updated.

**One approach** I am able to think - put the properties/map in S3 file, and let l1 poll it once every hour, to get the latest map/properties from S3(irrespective of if file is changed).

Q: how to achieve this(using AWS SDK for python)

*though the downfall is:* if I update the S3 file at 10:01 am (assuming polling done at 10am, 11am, 12pm etc), the map in l1 will be updated at 11am (and I am fine with it)

any other suggestion/approaches?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is rather confusing. Could you possibly Edit it to provide more information? For example, what do you mean by "populate it in a map for another function"? You can also trigger an AWS Lambda function when an S3 object is changed. That would be simpler than scheduling the function. What problems have you had with configuring this 'trigger'?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i tried to make it clear, though not sure if it makes some sense now

Answer (score 1):

Trigger function f1 from s3 whenever there is change in s3 file. and simply update map.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html

Comment: I update the question, can you please go through it one more time
@akshay Gopani

Comment: Put your map in S3 file. now you this map file directly on your code. first get the file from s3 when it require and convert into map.

Comment: yes, will put the map in S3, and let the lambda l1 load it first time by reading from S3.  
Now suppose I update the S3 file after a week by adding more key, val pair in the map.  



how the lambda l1 will know that map is updated?

Comment: Note: I dont want to read from S3 for each event from apigw which triggers lambda l1 to run the business logic (as lambda hold the mapping in a hashmap)

Comment: you have to read from s3 each time. or create seprate lambda which get trigger from s3 it will create new version of l1 each time new version contain new map values. better solution will be read from s3 each time. map data is only available  during run time so we have to update the version or read from s3 each time.